# what good libraries to use for paging on custom html (not table based)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have asp.net mvc website and in some pages i need a paging feature, and I want to use a good library to do that for me, the issue that I don't want this paging to render tables, I want it to render custom html i have such as li or div.

Which library you recommend for this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have successfully used [MvcPaging](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcPaging), it also allows you override the default pagination views with your own views.

You can install it via [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcPaging) with the following command  **Install-Package *MvcPaging***

Comment: Agree with Rijeesh. MvcPaging is a great library and you can overwrite the DisplayTemplate(string displayTemplate) property.  When set, the default HTML rendering is bypassed and a custom DisplayTemplate view can be used instead

Comment: As i saw in the demo project, it need to get all the records to be able to page on them, is that means that I should get all data records from the db and then give them to the MVCPaging to do its work?

Comment: @Amr ElGarhy - IMHO it depends on the IQueryable<T> object you pass to the extension method. If you are using EF/LINQ-SQL, the query that you generate will hit the database only when you call methods like .ToList(), .Count() etc... And inside the PagedList extension method it first execute the .Count() and then it loads only items which are needed for that  page using .Take() extension method. So it will send only two database requests - one for count and next for loading items which are needed for that page(not the all the rows in that table).

Answer (score 0):

you can use very easily jquery datatables
http://datatables.net/
they will allow you to insert HTML content and will handle the server side paging for you. so though you are  using tables they wont appear as one just keep one column and insert html content inside it.