# How to make paging start from 1 instead of 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I used the paging example of the [Nerddinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part8.htm) tutorial. But I also wanted to add page Numbers, somehting like that:

> <<< 1 2 3 4 5 6 >>>

The code below works if i start my paging from 0, but not from 1. How can I fix this ?

Here is my code:

**PaginatedList.cs**

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T> {

    public int PageIndex  { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize   { get; private set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize) {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        TotalCount = source.Count();
        TotalPages = (int) Math.Ceiling(TotalCount / (double)PageSize);

        this.AddRange(source.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage {
        get {
            return (PageIndex > 0);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage {
        get {
            return (PageIndex+1 < TotalPages);
        }
    }
}
```

**UserController.cs**

```
    public ActionResult List(int? page)
    {
        const int pageSize = 20;

        IUserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();
        IQueryable<User> listUsers = userRepository.GetAll();
        PaginatedList<User> paginatedUsers = new PaginatedList<User>(listUsers, page ?? 0, pageSize);

        return View(paginatedUsers);
    }
```

**List.cshtml**

```
@if (Model.HasPreviousPage) 
{ 
    @Html.RouteLink(" Previous ", "PaginatedUsers", new { page = (Model.PageIndex - 1) }) 
}

@for (int i = 1; i <=  Model.TotalPages; i++)
{
    @Html.RouteLink(@i.ToString(), "PaginatedUsers", new { page = (@i ) })   
}

@if (Model.HasNextPage)
{
    @Html.RouteLink(" Next ", "PaginatedUsers", new { page = (Model.PageIndex + 1) })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PaginatedList.cs

```
.Skip((PageIndex -1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize)
```

UserController.cs

```
public ActionResult List(int page = 1)
{
```

Comment: That gaves me this error : `Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: skipCount`

Comment: I rather used this : `page = (page < 1) ? 1 : page ?? 0;` to make sure that if the user change the url manually, it still works, but thanks for the clue !

Comment: it is wrong! if page is null return 0. Use:public ActionResult List(int page = 1)

Comment: If the user enter /List/Page/0, with your code, it will gives me the same error as the one above.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this changes :

**PaginatedList.cs**

```
public PaginatedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize) {
        .
        .
        .
        this.AddRange(source.Skip((PageIndex -1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
    }

public bool HasPreviousPage {
        get {
            return (PageIndex > 1);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage {
        get {
            return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
        }
    }
```

**UserController.cs**

```
    public ActionResult List(int? page)
    {
        const int pageSize = 20;

        page = (page < 1) ? 1 : page ?? 0;
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a library instead of going to write your own pagination code. [MvcPaging](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcPaging) is one of those library.

See my answer here - [what good libraries to use for paging on custom html (not table based)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432654/what-good-libraries-to-use-for-paging-on-custom-html-not-table-based/10468104#10468104)